# Which of the following partitions are of ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I want to completely uninstall ubuntu and reinstall it.

[image: gparted]

[image]

[image: Disk management]

Comment: sda8 and sda9. sda1 is sharing Ubuntu and Windows EFI.. Don't touch sda1

Comment: sda8 is your swap partition which is used by the OS when you don't have sufficient RAM left and sda9 contains your actual OS.